# IF statement in xslt for matching two id in BlogCategories

Tags: c#, xslt

I Want to match the blogcategory ParentID With Parent id..
Here is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <BlogCategories>
     <BlogCategory ID="1" ParentID="0" Name="Travel" Active="1" seo_keywords="Travel Blogs" seo_description="Travel Blogs" ParentName=""/>
     <BlogCategory ID="13" ParentID="1" Name="Destinations" Active="1" seo_keywords="Destinations" seo_description="Destinations" ParentName="Travel"/>
     <Parent Id="1" ParentName="Travel"/>
     <Parent Id="2" ParentName="HealthCare"/>
        </BlogCategories>
```

This is my .xslt page:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parent">
     <div class="grid-row3">
     <ul>
       <a href="">
         <xsl:value-of select="@ParentName"></xsl:value-of>
       </a>
       <xsl:for-each select="/BlogCategories/BlogCategory">
         <xsl:if test="@ParentID=@ID">
           <li>
             <a href="">
               <xsl:value-of select="@Name"></xsl:value-of>
             </a>
           </li>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </ul>
     </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that the ParentID of block category( `<BlogCategory ID="1" ParentID="0" Name="Travel" Active="1" seo_keywords="Travel Blogs" seo_description="Travel Blogs" ParentName=""/>)` does not match with ID of parent( `<Parent Id="1" ParentName="Travel"/>`)

i.e. If i do manually  `<xsl:if test="@ParentID=1">` then it will work..but if i do the same things ..then the problem is here: `<xsl:if test="@ParentID=@ID">`

How do i match `@ParentID=@ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/BlogCategories/BlogCategory">
```

with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/BlogCategories/BlogCategory[@ParentID = current()/@Id]">
```

Then you won't need the `xsl:if` instruction at all.

The way you are trying to do this could only work if you had stored the `Parent/@Id`value in a variable before calling `xsl:for-each`  - because the `xsl:for-each` instruction changes the context.

Another option (preferable, IMHO) is to use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) to resolve cross-references.

---

Note also that XML is case-sensitive: you cannot use `@ID` to select an attribute named `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a variable with Id parent :

```
<xsl:variable name="Id" select="@Id" />
```

and modify your condition with :

```
<xsl:if test="@ParentID=$Id">
```

the full code :

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parent">
  <xsl:variable name="Id" select="@Id" />
  <div class="grid-row3">
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ParentName"></xsl:value-of>
      </a>
      <xsl:for-each select="/BlogCategories/BlogCategory">
        <xsl:if test="@ParentID=$Id">
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <xsl:value-of select="@Name"></xsl:value-of>
            </a>
          </li>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```